# calling controllers with hook

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can I call a controller with a pre_controller hook.

Something like this, where ControllerHook is a normal controller.

```
$hook['pre_controller'][] = array(
  'class'    => 'ControllerHook',
  'function' => 'controllerHookFunction',
  'filename' => 'ControllerHook.php',
  'filepath' => 'hooks',
);
```

I tried this already, it works fine. On problem is that post hook processing I get this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function _assign_libraries() on a non-object in F:\xampp\htdocs\trunk\system\libraries\Loader.php on line 1038
```

I dont know what is the issue here.

I know I can do it easily extending the controller but I would prefer doing it with a hook.
With post_controller_* hook the controller hook doesnt execute.

Thanks in advance,
Shikhar

Comment: Could you post the code in question, please?

Comment: i formatted the question ... hope it makes sense now.

Comment: I see you have the same question open on the CI forums at http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/138816/#684238.  You should take his advice and just extend a parent class rather than using a hook.

Comment: thanks cballou . i did that already . but was curious . if i could call models from the hooks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should not be trying to do this. You should not ever need to call a Controller from anything, a Controller is called and that calls anything else.

There are lots of these confusing "how do I do this?" moments when you first start using CodeIgniter, but they are usually followed by "oh, I'm doing it wrong" realizations.

If you could explain your problem more thoroughly (here or in the forum post) I would be happy to help you work out the best implementation.